# linq to object using a list of tuples

Tags: c#, linq

I need to query a object collection in Entity framework and find the objects that meet a list of parameters.  For example and object could contain fields (p1, p2, p3, p4, .. pn).  I want to find the 3 objects for which the following are true (p1 = 3, p2 = 7, P3 =23), (p1 = 3, p2 = 43, p3 = 45), (p1 = 1, p2 =232, p3 = 321).

Since the collection could contain many elements and I could be looking for many (ex. 80) such tuples I do not want to do this in a loop since that would require a lot of round trips. I would prefer to do this is a single LINQ statement.  Is this possible?

Thanks,

Jerry

Comment: "I want to find the 3 objects" : Does this mean that there will be exactly *one* object that matches each condition? I'm a little confused because that appears to contradict "I could be looking for many (ex. 80) such tuples".

Comment: @Ani: I read it as he has many objects on the server, and he wants those 3 matches, ie: 3 objects returned... (Not sure that's a correct interpretation, though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do this.  Just do:

```
var matches = entities.Where(e => 
       (e.p1 == 3 && e.p2 == 7 && e.p3 == 23)
    || (e.p1 == 3 && e.p2 == 43 && e.p3 == 45)
    || (e.p1 == 1 && e.p2 == 232 && e.p3 == 321));
```

Comment: `just do` sounds interesting taking into account his `many (ex. 80)` tuples

Comment: @Snowbear: The way the question was worded, it sounded like the issue was avoiding round trips.  This does everything in a single round trip - granted, it's potentially ugly, but it's efficient in the respect of what the OP was trying to avoid...

Comment: agree that it will work for this **one** sample. I just do not see how to easily make it working if you have variable number of input criterias which I believe is the case in OP's question. Though it's only my guess, I do not know for sure.

Comment: @Snowbear: Yeah, it depends - hard to know without more information.  If its always 3 (or N) values, you can fill in variables, and this technique works.  If it's an unknown amount, it gets more difficult, as you'd have to build out the expression.

Comment: Thanks for all the great replies.  A little more data.  The number of parameters to match is fixed, most likely 2. The number of pairs of parameters is variable usually up to 20, but could be higher.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach, though I'm not sure that it will work with Linq-to-entity.

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> criterias = ...;

var filteredObjects = DataContext.YourObjects
                .Join(criterias, 
                      o => new {o.P1, o.P2, o.P3}, // your objects key
                      c => new {o.P1, o.P2, o.P3}, // criteria key
                      (o, c) => o);
```

Comment: You may need `YourObjects.AsEnumerable()` to get this to work.

Comment: @Gabe, it won't be what OP needs. He needs to filter it on SQL-side so downcasting to `IEnumerable` is not a good idea, though it will definitely make this coe working.

Comment: I don't think you can do a join on the server against an IEnumerable. To get this to work, then, you'll have to generate a predicate expression for a WHERE clause.